# Display a menu when clicking on an Image

Tags: jsf, primefaces, menu, menuitem

I want to create a primefaces menu component programmatically, here is the xhtml tag:

```
<p:menu model="#{notificationMenu.model}" />
```

and here is the spring component associated:

```
@Component
@Scope("session")
@Qualifier("notificationMenu")
public class NotificationMenu {

    @Autowired
    NotificationService notificationService;

    private MenuModel model;

    @PostConstruct
    public void createMenuModel() {

        List<Notification> listNotifs = notificationService.getAllUnreadNotifsForUser(LoginBean.getConnectedUser());

        model = new DefaultMenuModel();

        DefaultSubMenu subMenu = new DefaultSubMenu();

        for (Notification notification : listNotifs) {

            DefaultMenuItem item = new DefaultMenuItem();
            item.setValue(notification.getTypenotification().getTypenotif());
            item.setUrl("/user/index.xhtml");

            subMenu.addElement(item);
        }

        model.addElement(subMenu);
    }

    public MenuModel getModel() {
        return model;
    }
}
```

I'd like to programmatically associated this menu to a graphical image (like a notification image), so that when the user click on the image the menu is shown... is it possible?

---

EDIT :
I want the menu to be displayed **under** the image and **disappear on Blur** (clicking outside the image).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Overlay Menu**

A dynamic menu is created by setting `overlay` option to `true` and defining a trigger to show the
menu. Location of menu on page will be relative to the trigger and defined by `my` and `at` options
that take combination of four values:

- left
- right
- bottom
- top

That said:

```
<p:menu overlay="true" trigger="img"
        my="left top"
        at="bottom left"
        model="#{notificationMenu.model}" />
<p:graphicImage id="img" />
```